# Combine ElasticSearch aggregations on nested and non-nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

How do I combine the results from two bucket aggregations (in this case terms aggregations), one is on a nested field and the other is not. I would like to combine the results into a single list of buckets (with other sub aggregations included).

Example documents

```
{ "foo":
  { "nesty": [
    { "bar":{"id":1}},
    { "bar":{"id":2}}
    ]
  }
}

{ "foo": { "bar" : {"id": 1} } }
```

Here's what I have tried so far

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "a": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "foo.nesty"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "a": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "foo.nesty.bar.id"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "b": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "for.bar.id"
      }
    },
    "c":{
      "<some pipeline agg>":{...},
      "aggs": {...}
    }
  }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a pipeline aggregation that lets me combine the buckets from the other two.

I have also tried combining the two using a script in the terms aggregation:

```
 "c": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "foo.nesty"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "c": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "(doc['for.bar.id'].value != null) ? doc['for.bar.id'].value : doc['foo.nesty.bar.id']"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {...}
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work! Once I use nested I can't seem to access the other fields. Conversely, if I use reverse_nested inside a sub aggregation I won't have access to the nested fields.

**Is there any way to access both in a script?**

If I could do that I could make it work.

Just for clarity I expect this sort of response back:

```
{
  ...

  "aggregations" : {
      "c" : {  
          "buckets" : [ 
            {
                "key" : "1",
                "doc_count" : 2
            },
            {
                "key" : "2",
                "doc_count" : 1
            }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

Example mapping:

```
"mappings": {
  "test": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
          "bar": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "nesty": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "bar": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "properties": {
                  "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: need to see your mappings and schema

Comment: @user3775217 mapping included, thanks!